# Elasticsearch 5.1 подсветка результатов

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Добрый день,

Использую Elasticsearch 5.1 для хранения сущностей. 
Кто подскажет как сделать поиск и подсветку для всех полей?

```
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder()
            .postTags("<highlight>")
            .preTags("</highlight>")
            .highlightQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery( "ferrari"));


    SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch("notemates")
            .setTypes("cars")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery( "ferrari"))
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .highlighter(highlightBuilder);
    SearchResponse response = request.get();
```

Подскажите где я не прав.
Спасибо

Comment: Судя по докам - дело в highlightQuery, ее, скорее всего, указывать не нужно вообще. В случае, если ее надо указывать, она не может совпадать с обычной query - это структурно разные вещи.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, без нее так же не работает

Comment: постараюсь на выходных проработать (самому интересно), но пока не знаю, будет ли время

Comment: @etki спасибо, пишите!

Answer (score 3):

У себя делаю без дополнительного билдера. Вроде все работает...

```
    List<String> highlightedFields = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    final SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch(filter.getIndexName())
            .addSort(...)
            .setQuery(...)
            .setFrom(...)
            .setSize(...);
    ...
    for (String str : highlightedFields) {
        builder.addHighlightedField(str, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: К сожелению в версии 5.1.1 нет метода addHighlightedField()